# Change IP via C++

Tags: c++, windows, networking

I try to change my IP address programmatically, via C++. Maybe it's impossible ? I found this Code ++ :

```
bool MyMethod(char oldIPAddress[], char newIPAddress[], char newMaskAddress[])
{
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = NULL;

    ULONG ulOutBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
    if (pAdapterInfo == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
    {
        free(pAdapterInfo);
        pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(ulOutBufLen);
        if (pAdapterInfo == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) == NO_ERROR)
    {
        pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
        while (pAdapter)
        {
            if (strcmp(oldIPAddress, pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String) == 0)
            {
                IPAddr addr = inet_addr(newIPAddress);
                IPMask mask = inet_addr(newMaskAddress);
                ULONG context, instance;

                if (DeleteIPAddress(pAdapter->IpAddressList.Context) != NO_ERROR
                    || AddIPAddress(addr, mask, pAdapter->Index, &context, &instance) != NO_ERROR)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;  // not return true
            }
            pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
        }
        return false;   // return false  here
    }
};
```

Program is compiling and run without Exceptions, but `MyMethod` always return `false`. if I use cmd>ipconfig - IP address still old. Where is my error ?

Comment: Did you debug the code and check where it returns false?

Comment: It returns `false` because it has failed, why do you expect `cmd>ipconfig - IP` return anything else but the old address?

Comment: Also why this doesn't give you the warning that method might not return `bool` in all cases?

Comment: @Philipp it must return`true` here -  `if (DeleteIPAddress(pAdapter->IpAddressList.Context) != NO_ERROR` but this does not happen

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to above method is calling the `netsh` command from the command shell.

Syntax for setting the IP and Netmask is :

`netsh interface ipv4 set address name="YOUR INTERFACE NAME" static IP_ADDRESS SUBNET_MASK GATEWAY`

Interface name can be obtained from the ipconfig command as you stated.

Fill the above `netsh` command to a string with the desired Interface Name, IP and Netmask parameters and use `system(commandString);` to execute the command in the commandString.

Comment: it's work great, but when I change ip address, my internet connection is lost. what can I do for prevent?

Comment: What is the IP address and Netmask you can use with internet? What is the one you set that causes connection to drop?

Comment: Also if you can tell what are you trying to achieve you can get better help.